# Wcf service not running in a Different Computer

Tags: wcf

I have written a WCF Services and made it Restful by using `[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")]` below the `[OperationContract]` in each method.

Now this service is running fine and I can invoke any method by SoapUI or Fiddler. The Url for invoking a method is like

```
localhost:4030/Catalogue.svc/MethodName
```

Even when I am typing

```
localhost:4030/Catalogue.svc/help
```

I can see all methods i.e everything is working fine in the service.

Problem is when I am running the same solution on a different computer; first it is throwing a configuration compatibility error, after googling I found this is due to Processor Incompatibility so I changed CPU to x86 in Visual Studio but still the issue was there so I tried in release mode instead of Debug and it run successfully saying service added successfully, but when I am trying to invoke any method or help command it is throwing 400 error.

On both computers the service is running in IIS Express. I spent 2 days in that but still didn't find any solution

Comment: Check if port open and accessible as per firewall policies. Check the path as well under which it is available. Check that SVC extension is registered in IIS

Comment: @sunil singhal Bro I am running solution in IIS Express and can u please elaborate how to check path .